# Target already exists error in hadoop put command

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, put

I am trying my hands on Hadoop 1.0. I am getting `Target  does not exists` while copying one file from local system into HDFS.

My hadoop command and its output is as follows :

```
shekhar@ubuntu:/host/Shekhar/Softwares/hadoop-1.0.0/bin$ hadoop dfs -put /host/Users/Shekhar/Desktop/Downloads/201112/20111201.txt .
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

put: Target  already exists
```

After observing the output, we can see that there are two blank spaces between word 'Target' and 'already'. I think there has to be something like `/user/${user}` between those 2 words. If I give destination path explicitly as `/user/shekhar` then I get following error :

```
shekhar@ubuntu:/host/Shekhar/Softwares/hadoop-1.0.0/bin$ hadoop dfs -put /host/Users/Shekhar/Desktop/Downloads/201112/20111201.txt /user/shekhar/data.txt
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

put: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Parent path is not a directory: /user/shekhar
```

Output of `ls` command is as follows :

```
shekhar@ubuntu:/host/Shekhar/Softwares/hadoop-1.0.0/bin$ hadoop dfs -lsr /
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

drwxr-xr-x   - shekhar supergroup          0 2012-02-21 19:56 /tmp
drwxr-xr-x   - shekhar supergroup          0 2012-02-21 19:56 /tmp/hadoop-shekhar
drwxr-xr-x   - shekhar supergroup          0 2012-02-21 19:56 /tmp/hadoop-shekhar/mapred
drwx------   - shekhar supergroup          0 2012-02-21 19:56 /tmp/hadoop-shekhar/mapred/system
-rw-------   1 shekhar supergroup          4 2012-02-21 19:56 /tmp/hadoop-shekhar/mapred/system/jobtracker.info
drwxr-xr-x   - shekhar supergroup          0 2012-02-21 19:56 /user
-rw-r--r--   1 shekhar supergroup    6541526 2012-02-21 19:56 /user/shekhar
```

Please help me in copying file into HDFS. If you need any other information then please let me know.

I am trying this in Ubuntu which is installed using WUBI (Windows Installer for ubuntu).

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Hi, i am also running into the same problem. Could you please suggest the soltuion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-rw-r--r--   1 shekhar supergroup    6541526 2012-02-21 19:56 **/user/shekhar**

shekhar@ubuntu:/host/Shekhar/Softwares/hadoop-1.0.0/bin$ hadoop dfs -put /host/Users/Shekhar/Desktop/Downloads/201112/20111201.txt **/user/shekhar/data.txt**

Comment: I am getting java.io.FileNotFoundException if I try to put file in this way

Answer (score 3):

The problem in the put command is the trailing `.`.  You need to specify the full path *on HDFS* where you want the file to go, for ex:

`hadoop fs -put /host/Users/Shekhar/Desktop/Downloads/201112/20111201.txt /whatever/20111201.txt`

If the directory that you are putting the file in doesn't exist yet, you need to create it first:

`hadoop fs -mkdir /whatever`

The problem that you are having when you specify the path explicitly is that on your system, /user/shekar is a *file*, not a *directory*.  You can see that because it has a non-0 size.

Answer (score 0):

you must make the file first!

`hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/hadoop
hdfs dfs -put /home/bigdata/.password  /user/hadoop/`